# flutter - how draw line by timer on widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have this widget:

[image]

this is his code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: this.scrollController,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(
        children: getItems()));
}

List<Widget> getItems() {
var items = List<Widget>();

for( var i = 0 ; i <= 20; i=i+1 ) {
   var curr = Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
    child: Text(i.toString(), 
      style: textStyle,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  );
  items.add(curr);
}
return items;
```

}

I have this timer:

```
Timer _timer;

@override
void initState() {
_timer =Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) => setState((){
 super.initState(); 
}));
```

I need to display a line on my widget every second:
start - draw on 0,
1 sec - draw on 1(the leading line is deleted)
2 sec - draw on 2(the leading line is deleted)
and etc.

Example:

start -[image]

1 sec -[image]

2 sec -[image]

I need a "demonstration of time." this is the movement of the indicator (line) from left to right. Probably an animation would do.

what do you advise? I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: There may be a better solution, but you can always go to use the `CustomPainter` and `canvas` directly

Comment: can i draw a line on my widget using CustomPainter? Or should I draw on the canvas?

Comment: You can use a `CustomPainter` instead of your widget, and draw both the lines and the numbers using this `CustomPainter`, then you wrap that widget with another `StatefulWidget` and use an animation to change the position of the drawn line, but as I told you there may be a better solution

Comment: Is this just a purpose for showing or any interaction is associate? If this is just for showing, flare is preferable.

Comment: I need a "demonstration of time." this is the movement of the indicator (line) from left to right.